# How to 'difference' one vector from another?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create a mute music button:

[image]

And I'm doing it by drawing 2 vector lines over a music note vector.  I've tried selecting them every which way but whenever I try to take the path → difference nothing happens.  Ideally I'd like to subtract the big like (white in the above image) and add the small line.

How would I do this?

Comment: You could say I'm trying to do the opposite of this:
http://inkscapetutorials.org/2014/04/22/inkscape-faq-how-do-i-crop-in-inkscape/

Comment: This is the file if you want a closer look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7h5sk17R61RWpOUV9aaXlaM0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it, I had to be in the edit paths mode: http://imgur.com/3YQaUfL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  You have to be in the edit paths mode:

[image]

You may also need to convert the object into a path.  Path → Object to Path